# How to get an exact size of a GtkTextBuffer in bytes?

Tags: gtk

At the present time I'm doing it like:

```
GtkTextBuffer *buf = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(...);
gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds(buf, &start, &end);
gchar *data = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(buf, &start, &end, true);
gint size = strlen(data); // ouch
```

But this is rather ugly. I found (and tested) `gtk_text_iter_get_offset()` but it returns the size in *characters*, not physical bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Since GTK+ stores all text in UTF-8 by definition, I think your solution to get a pointer to the characters and use a plain old `strlen()` is awesome.

UTF-8 guarantees that the byte with value 0 does not occur, so `strlen()` will perform the proper counting operation and return the length of the buffer in bytes. Plus, it's a classic C runtime function that is well-known and very probably as highly optimized as possible.

Comment: '\0' _is not_ invalid UTF-8: http://www.mail-archive.com/gtk-devel-list@gnome.org/msg08985.html
Some GTK+ API yet provides the length parameter to allow embedding NUL bytes.

Comment: @ntd: Interesting. But is it possible to type (or otherwise cause) a NUL-byte to appear in a GtkTextBuffer?

Comment: @unwind: I don't know, NUL handling is still an open issue. I suspect embedding a NUL byte, although valid UTF8, will break a lot of code anyway. My comment was more academic than practical.

Answer (score 0):

There's no corresponding `gtk_text_buffer_get_byte_count()` or `gtk_text_iter_get_index()` function, unfortunately. If you need an absolute upper bound on the number of bytes required to store the buffer text, you could take the value from `gtk_text_buffer_get_char_count()` and multiply it by 4, the maximum number of bytes required to encode one UTF-8 character. If it's allocating and deallocating a string holding the full text of the buffer you're worried about, you could do the following:

```
glong bytecount = 0;
GtkTextIter iter;
for(gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buf, &iter); gtk_text_iter_forward_line(&iter); )
    bytecount += gtk_text_iter_get_bytes_in_line(&iter);
```

I don't claim that this isn't ugly.

Answer (score 0):

strlen() stops at the first space encountered.
I suggest a modified version:

```
short int strlen_0(char *s)
{ short int i=0;
  if (s!=NULL)
     {while (*(s+i)!='\0') i++;
      return i;}
  else return -1;}
```